# How to change Windows TextBox background color?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, themes

Every time I try to use a dark theme in Windows 7, it makes text in textboxes illegible (as shown below). How can I change the default colour of the text-boxes alone (like with the Stylish add-on in web-browers), without changing the entire theme?

[image]

Comment: Sorry wizzwizz2, I want to change the entire theme. The problem is Windows Explorer. Nobody seems to find a way to customize texboxes (text and background colors).

Comment: Naturally, I don't want to make my own theme; there are hundreds of great themes on the web. I only want to use a dark theme, but Microsoft doesn't allow it.

Comment: This community is really pathetic. You write something like "I don't want to change the entire theme" and some idiot arrives and edit the comment in "I want to change the entire theme". And this happens everytime. I didn't think there could be anything more useless than Microsoft forums, but you've gone beyond that limit. Pseudo experts who know nothing and talk from morning to evening. I delete my account. Naturally, nobody will read this comment; because it will be edited right now. :)